# Looping through parallel lists/arrays in an SPSS macro

Tags: macos, statistics, spss

I would like to write a SPSS macro to perform three operations:

1. generate a custom table,
2. clean the output window,
3. export table.

As you know SPSS macro facility allows to use two types of loops: 'numeric' like (`!do !i = !x !to !y`) and 'list'/'for each' like (`!do !i !in (!1)`). My goal is to create a macro with a call as below:
`col v1 v2 / "Sheet A" "Sheet B".`
working this way (with a 'list' like loop):

1. Get first variable name (v1)
2. Put it in the `ctables` macro section
3. Get first sheet name (string "Sheet A")
4. Put it in the `output export` macro section
5. Get second variable name
6. ...
7. Get second sheet name
8. ...

and so on.

At first I wrote this:

```
define col (!positional !charend('/')
/!positional !cmdend)

!do !i !in (!1)

output close all.

  ctables
  /table x1 + x2
  by !i [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].

  output modify
  /select logs headings texts warnings pagetitles outlineheaders notes
  /deleteobject delete = yes.

!doend

!do !i !in (!2)

   output export
    /contents export = visible
    /xlsx documentfile = "E:\path\file.xlsx"
      operation = createsheet
      sheet = !i.

!doend

!enddefine.

*** MACRO CALL.
col v1 v2 / "Sheet A" "Sheet B".
```

The output was overall incorrect because I got tables only with the second variable. However, in the file I found two sheets with correct names. So, I tried nesting:

```
define col (!positional !charend('/')
/!positional !cmdend)

!do !i !in (!1)
!do !j !in (!2)

output close all.

  ctables
  /table x1 + x2
  by !i [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].

  output modify
  /select logs headings texts warnings pagetitles outlineheaders notes
  /deleteobject delete = yes.

   output export
    /contents export = visible
    /xlsx documentfile = "E:\path\file.xlsx"
      operation = createsheet
      sheet = !j.

!doend
!doend

!enddefine.

*** MACRO CALL.
col v1 v2 / "Sheet A" "Sheet B".
```

The output was exactly the same meaning SPSS crosses each element from the list on the left side of '/' with each element from the list on the right side of '/' and overwrites previous results in Excel file. My goal is to receive macro expansions like this:

```
* FIRST EXPANSION:
...
  ctables
  /table x1 + x2
  by v1 [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].
...
   output export
    /contents export = visible
    /xlsx documentfile = "E:\path\file.xlsx"
      operation = createsheet
      sheet = "Sheet A".

* SECOND (LAST) EXPANSION:
...
  ctables
  /table x1 + x2
  by v2 [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].
...
   output export
    /contents export = visible
    /xlsx documentfile = "E:\path\file.xlsx"
      operation = createsheet
      sheet = "Sheet B".
```

In other words - 2 lists x 2 elements but only two loops - not four. Does anyone have any idea how to get such result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no formal/direct way to run a loop on parallel lists in SPSS macro, so your options are - either go Python, or find a workaround - here are a few ideas:

**1. Recreate both lists using a number loop**
so you loop on the numbers say 1 to 5, and use them to create the variable names -
v1 to v5 and "sheet 1" to "sheet 5":

```
!do !i=1 !to 5
.....
  by !concat("v",!i) [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].
.....
  sheet = !quote(!concat("sheet ",!i))
.....
!doend
```

You can also add the beginning and\or end numbers to the macro call if they aren't constants.
This of course will work only if your two lists share a common numbering as in the example above. If they don't, you can use one of the following:

**2. Loop through one list while "eating through" the second one**
The SPSS macro loop only iterates through one list at a time - but instead of iterating through the second list you can take an item and delete it from the second list for every iteration of the first list:

```
define col (!pos !charend('/') / !pos !cmdend)
!let !arr2=!2
!do !i !in(!1)
    .....
    by !i [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].
    .....
!let !sheet=!head(!arr2)
!let !arr2=!tail(!arr2)
    .....
    sheet = !sheet
    .....
!doend
!enddefine.

*and the macro call:
col VARa VARb VARc/"sheet 1" "sheet 2" "sheet 3".
```

**3. Define the macro on a single pair, use multiple macro calls** 
This is the simplest way, if you only have a couple of items in each list - You can define the macro with a single variable name and a single sheet name, you'll be able to get the same results by running -

```
col VARa/ "sheet 1" .
col VARb/ "sheet 2" .
```

instead of `col VARa VARb/ "sheet 1" "sheet 2" .` As you tried before.

If these lists are long, you can automate running the macro calls separately (using `write` command for example - but this is for a separate question).

Comment: There's another, 4th solution but not as effective, flexible and neat as 2nd:
`define col (!positional !charend('/')
/!positional !cmdend)

!do !i !in (!1)

!if (!i = "v1") !then
!let !sheetname = "Sheet A"
!ifend
!if (!i = "v2") !then
!let !sheetname = "Sheet B"
!ifend

...

  ctables
  /table x1 + x2
  by !i [mean f1.2, totals[mean f1.2]].

...

   output export
    /contents export = visible
    /xlsx documentfile = "E:\path\file.xlsx"
      operation = createsheet
      sheet = !sheetname.

!doend

!enddefine.

*** MACRO CALL.
col v1 v2.`

Comment: well this would work for the example but the downside is it will not be dynamic for new situations...

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's why solution number 2 is the best.