# Nested macros in SPSS and !IF-!THEN command with calculation as a condition

Tags: spss

I need to do a calculation for several years. I could of course call the macro for each year separately. However, I would prefer to call the macro only once and work with additional nested index-loops (`!DO !var = x !TO y`).

My problem is now that I also need an !IF-!THEN-condition that contains a calculation: `!IF (!year = !prev_year+1) !THEN`
However, this seems not possible. I then wrote the second part of the calculation in an extra Syntax that I insert afterwards. It works, but not properly. Below you find a Syntax with an example.

```
DEFINE !change_hh (lastyear = !TOKENS(1) / lastyear_minus_1=!TOKENS(1) / bedingung = !TOKENS(1) / eyear = !TOKENS(1))
!DO !year= 2011 !TO !lastyear.
    !DO !prevyear= 2010 !TO !lastyear_minus_1.
    COMPUTE prevyear= !year-1.
    exe.
    ALTER TYPE prevyear (F4.0).
    DO IF $casenum = 1.
    WRITE OUTFILE=!QUOTE(!CONCAT("path\anyname_",!year,".sps"))
     /"DEFINE @bedingung() ", prevyear, " !ENDDEFINE.".
    END IF.
    EXE.  

    INSERT FILE = !QUOTE(!CONCAT("path\anyname_",!year,".sps")). 
        !IF (!prevyear= !EVAL(!bedingung)) !THEN
                COMPUTE !CONCAT("test_year_",!eyear) = !eyear.
                COMPUTE !CONCAT("test_prevyear_",!prevyear) = !prevyear.
                exe.
        !IFEND.
    !DOEND.
!DOEND.
EXE.
!ENDDEFINE.
!change_hh lastyear_minus_1 = 2014 lastyear= 2015 bedingung = @bedingung eyear = @jahr.
```

I only get the variables `test_year_2015` and `test_prevyear_2014`. What is wrong? I just don't get it. 
I thought that it first works with year = 2011 and goes through all the prevyears. After, it works with year = 2012 and goes again through all the prevyears. And so on.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPSS macro can only use macro arguments as (textual) building blocks to create syntax with. Among other limitations, this means that the macro can't perform mathematical operations on arguments as in `!IF (!year = !prev_year+1) !then`.

Another limitation of SPSS macro makes it hard to loop on two separate date arrays - which would be a natural solution here ([see my answer here for an idea about how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60605471/looping-through-parallel-lists-arrays-in-an-spss-macro/60607877#60607877)).

STILL - here is a possible suggestion about how to get the same effect here:

```
define ....
.....
!let !prevyr="2010"
!do !year= 2011 !to !lastyear.
  ... use arguments !year and !prevyr ....
  !let !prevyr=!year
!doend
```

In this loop, at the end of every iteration, the `!prevyr` argument receives the value or `!year` argument and is ready for the next iteration.